# Adding image onload to canvas inside a method does not work

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, onload, drawimage

I have a Javascript class with a method which loads an image and adds it to a canvas.

At first I was doing this:

```
var context = this.cardCanvas.getContext('2d');
var cardWidth = this.cardWidth;
var img = new Image();
img.src = '../shared/images/logo.png';
context.drawImage(img, (cardWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2), 75);
```

This works about 8 out of 10 times, so I was looking for a solution to make it work consistently every time. Many websites and SO posts state to use code like this:

```
var context = this.cardCanvas.getContext('2d');
var cardWidth = this.cardWidth;
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img, (cardWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2), 75);
};
img.src = '../shared/images/logo.png';
```

But when I do this the image is never added to the canvas, although debugging shows that the onload method is called.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: The image node has to be present in your DOM. Add your image to the end of the DOM and set the parent node `display: none`

Answer (score 0):

I think the second snippet works perfectly and the first does not work at all, I don't know how you're getting a blank canvas with the second, consider the following snippet where unchecked checkbox renders image without `onload` event else `onload` event is being defined:

```js
function load() {
  var context = cardCanvas.getContext('2d');
  var cardWidth = 500;
  var img = new Image();

  context.clearRect(100, 0, 200, 200);
  //unchecked - without onload
  if (!document.querySelector('input').checked) {
    img.src = 'http://placekitten.com/200/75';
    context.drawImage(img, (cardWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2), 75);
  }
  //checked - with onload
  else {
    img.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(img, (cardWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2), 75);
    };
    img.src = 'http://placekitten.com/200/75';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<button onclick="load()">load</button>
<canvas id="cardCanvas"></canvas>
```